# Killed explorer.exe, but when I maximize a window, a 'ghost taskbar' is still there

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, taskbar, windows-shell

I'm trying to implement my own shell written in C#, using the Windows Presentation Foundation library. The first logical step to completely replace the shell is to get rid of the old one.

The first thing I did was I killed `explorer.exe` by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, right-clicking on the taskbar and clicking “Exit Explorer”. The taskbar disappeared as expected, but whenever I maximize a window it doesn't fill the entire screen and the space reserved for the taskbar is still there.

The question is, how can I get rid of that space?

Comment: Taskkill the SearchUI.exe (for Cortana) and ShellExperienceHost.exe (start menu) and rename them so that they does not reappear automatically.

Comment: I just tried that but it didn't work. The space is still there.

Comment: I have 2 monitors and by default, the task bar is visible on both. When I do what you said, the task bar disappears on the secondary screen but not on the primary.

Comment: Then taskkill and rename the both exe files as I mentioned. Then restart the explorer.exe and then kill explorer in both monitor.